# java.lang.NumberFormatException in jdbc project

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to run a JDBC project, sf employee management and payroll
I'm posting my codes, Anyone can please help

```
package com.ibs.emp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DBConnectionTest {

    static ResultSet rs;
    static ResultSetMetaData rm;
    static int ch, nof;
    static double tax, total;
    static EmpDetails empDetails = new EmpDetails();

    public static double gross(){  
        if(EmpDetails.getHours() > 40)      
            return EmpDetails.getHours() * EmpDetails.getOrate();
        else
            return EmpDetails.getHours() * EmpDetails.getRate();
    }

    public static double net(){
        if(EmpDetails.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("married"))
            return total *= 0.75;
        else
            return total *= 0.70;
    }

    public static void display(double total, double tax){
        System.out.println("Gross pay: " + total);
        System.out.println("Net pay: " + tax);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();

        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
        Connection con = dbConnection.getConnection();
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Choose Option");
            System.out.println("1. Select");
            System.out.println("2. Insert");
            System.out.println("3. Update");
            System.out.println("4. Delete");
            System.out.println("5. Payslip");
            System.out.println("0. Exit");
            ch = Integer.parseInt(bin.readLine());
            if (ch==1){
                rs = st.executeQuery("select * from emp");
                rm = rs.getMetaData();
                nof = rm.getColumnCount();
                for(int i=1; i<=nof; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(rm.getColumnName(i)+"\t\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    for(int i=1; i<=nof; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(rs.getString(i) +"\t\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            else if(ch==2)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Name");
                empDetails.setEmp_name(bin.readLine());
                System.out.println("Enter Designation");
                empDetails.setEmp_designation(bin.readLine());
                System.out.println("Enter Emp_age");
                empDetails.setEmp_age( bin.read());
                System.out.println("Enter Salary");
                empDetails.setEmp_salary(bin.read());
                System.out.println("How many hours worked?");
                empDetails.setHours(bin.read());
                System.out.println("Rate of pay?");
                empDetails.setRate(bin.read());
                System.out.println("Over time rate?");
                empDetails.setOrate(bin.read());
                System.out.println("Married or Single?");
                empDetails.setStatus(bin.readLine());
                total = gross();
                tax = net();

                st.execute("insert into emp values('"+empDetails.getEmp_name()+"','"+empDetails.getEmp_age()+"','"+empDetails.getEmp_designation()+"','"+empDetails.getEmp_salary()+"','"+empDetails.getStatus()+"','"+empDetails.getOrate()+"','"+empDetails.getRate()+"','"+empDetails.getHours()+"','toatal','tax')");
                System.out.println("1 Record inserted");
            }
            else if(ch==3)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Emp_id");
                empDetails.setEmp_id(bin.read());
                System.out.println("Enter Name");
                empDetails.setEmp_name( bin.readLine());
                System.out.println("Enter Designation");
                empDetails.setEmp_designation(bin.readLine());
                System.out.println("Enter Emp_age");
                empDetails.setEmp_age( bin.read());
                System.out.println("Enter Salary");
                empDetails.setEmp_salary(bin.read());
                System.out.println("How many hours worked?");
                empDetails.setHours(bin.read());
                System.out.println("Rate of pay?");
                empDetails.setEmp_name(bin.readLine());
                System.out.println("Over time rate?");
                empDetails.setEmp_name(bin.readLine());
                System.out.println("Married or Single?");
                empDetails.setEmp_name(bin.readLine());
                total = gross();
                tax = net();

                st.execute("update emp set emp_name='"+empDetails.getEmp_name()+"',emp_age='"+empDetails.getEmp_age()+"',emp_designation='"+empDetails.getEmp_designation()+"',emp_salary='"+empDetails.getEmp_salary()+"',status='"+empDetails.getStatus()+"',orate='"+empDetails.getOrate()+"',rate='"+empDetails.getRate()+"',hours='"+empDetails.getHours()+"',taotal='toatal',tax='tax' where emp_id ="+empDetails.getEmp_id());
                System.out.println("1 Record Updated");

            }
            else if(ch==4)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Emp_id. to Delete :");
                empDetails.setEmp_id(bin.read());
                st.execute("delete from emp where eno ="+empDetails.getEmp_id());
                System.out.println("Record Deleted");
            }
            else if(ch==5)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Emp_id");
                empDetails.setEmp_id(bin.read());
                rs = st.executeQuery("select * from emp");
                rm = rs.getMetaData();
                nof = rm.getColumnCount();
                for(int i=1; i<=nof; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(rm.getColumnName(i)+"\t\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    for(int i=1; i<=nof; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(rs.getString(i) +"\t\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                display(total, tax);
            }
            else if(ch==0)
            {
                bin.close();
                con.close();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm getting following error.
**Console**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibs.emp.DBConnectionTest.main(DBConnectionTest.java)
```

Any suggestions are welcomed, please help

Comment: An empty string can not formated a s number

Comment: please use prepared statement instead, your code is open to an sql injection

Comment: a NumberFormatException is an Exception that might be thrown when you try to convert a String into a number, where that number might be an int, a float, or any other Java numeric type. Hence what you can do is review/debug it.

Comment: @rabbitguy. No there error must be in a line where main directly calls `Integer.valueOf()` see the stacktrace. I guess it is in this line: `ch = Integer.parseInt(bin.readLine());` where only a EOL is entered.  Where OP call `rs.getString(i)` is no Need to parse it as an int

Comment: for(int i=1; i<=nof; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(rs.getString(i) +"\t\t");
                    }

Comment: Here might the problem.

Comment: @Abhishek: please Show the line where your error occurs

Comment: Exception normally shows the line number also where it happened, can't see in the trace...

Comment: He hasn't posted the full StackTrace though.

Comment: learning to step through with a debugger will be extremely beneficial to your career

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass some integer value while running your code, try passing some argument while running. If you are using eclipse IDE then you have to go to run configuration and click argument tab to pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused if there is no option selected. This might happen if the user just clicks on Enter without selecting an option for example.

Try to replace the line:

```
ch = Integer.parseInt(bin.readLine());
```

by

```
String readLine = bin.readLine();
ch = Integer.parseInt(readLine != null && !readLine.isEmpty() ? readLine : "0");
```